# What's wrong with ImageIO.write. It doesn't write the image back or show it?

Tags: java, image-processing, javax.imageio

The purpose of this program in to get the negative of a gray scale image. When I run, nothing appears and the resulted image doesn't show up. After debugging, everything works fine except the ImageIO.write function. Any idea why ?

```
import java.awt.BufferCapabilities;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class emancv {

    public  static void main(String[] args){
    String filepath = "D:\\Eman Hamed\\Academics\\Fall 14\\Computer Vision\\flower.jpg";
        try {
                BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File(filepath));
                BufferedImage output = negative(bi);
                ImageIO.write(output, "jpg", new File("D:\\Eman Hamed\\Academics\\Fall 14\\Computer Vision\\flower2.jpg"));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    public static BufferedImage negative(BufferedImage bi){
        WritableRaster myImage = bi.copyData(null);
        WritableRaster myImage2 = bi.copyData(null);
        for(int i =0; i< myImage2.getHeight(); i++)
            for(int j =0; j<myImage2.getWidth(); j++)
            {
                int value = 255 - myImage.getSample(j, i, 0);
                myImage2.setSample(j, i, 0, value);
            }
         BufferedImage res= new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(),bi.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        res.setData(myImage2);
        return res;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `ImageIO.write()` returns a `boolean` indicating whether the image was written to file or not. It's not very useful to figure out *why* in some cases the image isn't written, but at least it is a starting point. What does it return in your case? If `false`, check for the obvious things like; Is the path correct? Do you have write permission? etc...

Comment: Does it create an empty file? I'm getting the problem where it creates a file where I tell it to, but the file has not a single byte of data.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake, replace this line

```
BufferedImage res= newBufferedImage(bi.getWidth(),bi.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
```

by this one

```
BufferedImage res= new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(),bi.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
```

and it will be OK

Comment: I copy/paste your code and everything is ok while I change filepaths... be sure to have access to "D:\Eman Hamed\Academics\Fall 14\Computer Vision\flower.jpg" and "D:\Eman Hamed\Academics\Fall 14\Computer Vision\flower2.jpg"